# Difference between AAD and MSI

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-keyvault

I am new to Azure.While exploring Azure KMS service usage with Azure SDK (as i need my application to communicate with Azure services), i came across AAD, where i did new app registration and then use the service principal in KMS.

Now, thing is i can achieve same thing with Managed Service Identity.So whats the difference between 2 approaches.Which one is best?

Below are the referred links :

```
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/managed-identities-azure-resources/overview][1]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, it is better to use a managed identity (either system assigned or user assigned) than an app registration which you manage yourself.

When you create an app registration (an Application object) and you instantiate that app in a tenant (a ServicePrincipal object), you have to manage the credentials for that app. You need to securely generate, store and renew credentials (a secret or a certificate), and you need to use this credential in your application's code to obtain an access token.

A managed identity will also have a corresponding ServicePrincipal object in Azure AD. However, with a managed identity you no longer have to worry about generating, renewing or securing the credentials. All that is *managed* for you by the service, giving you a very simple interface to obtain tokens, and allowing you to focus on building your solution.

There are some scenarios where you can't directly use a managed identity (e.g. if you are building a web app and want to implement the Authorization Code flow, you can't use the managed identity as your OAuth 2.0 client). In these cases, it is often very useful to use a managed identity to bootstrap you app's access to the credentials: use your service's managed identity to get access to a certificate or secret stored in Azure Key Vault, then use that credential as part of regular OAuth 2.0 flows (e.g. using the MSAL library).

Comment: I am trying to use msi to access Blob Storage containers. But every time i am tryig to access , i am getting following error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create Shared Access Signature unless the Account Key credentials are used by the ServiceClient.  I dont want to access blob storage container using credentials or AAD. Just want to use msi, as this is the unique mode that we want to adapt in our application to access Azure resources.Raised separate thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57349028/ava-lang-illegalargumentexception-cannot-create-shared-access-signature-unless

Answer (score 1):

There is not difference *between*, as it are no equals. Managed Identies are built *on top* of Azure Active Directory (AAD).

There are 2 types of Managed Identies: User assigned and system assigned. The difference between using a service principal vs a managed identity is that in the latter case you do not have to deal with secrets. Also, when using a system assigned managed identity the identity is deleted once the resource that has created it is removed. When using an user assigned identity or a service principal you will have to do that manually.

Now, there never is a best option. Thing is, not all azure resources do support managed identities. But if they do I would prefer to use them so I do not have to register applications in the AAD myself and have to use their secrets to allow access to other resources. Basically creating a managed identity will create an identity in the AAD.

Some understandable and readably overview can be found [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2018/04/13/demystifying-managed-service-identities-on-azure/).